# Storing the data of Html Table while button click event fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am stuck in a situation, web site is running in **ASP.NET 1.1**

I am loading a page with some data. In the page there is a Html Table.
**In each row, I am loading status(active/inactive) in one  and message  in another .**

There is a save button when clicked it should save the status and message to database.

Since the data is in **Html Table I am loosing the data while button is clicked.**

I tried one option of keeping the status and message at page load in a global Javascript variable. But I will loose that also when button is clicked.

JS Code to store the data :

```
// To store all active or inactive feature values.
var arrType = [];
var interiorValues = [arrType];
var exteriorValues = [];
var mechanicalValues = [];
var standardValues = [];

function StoreChromeVallue()
{
    var $jDecode = jQuery.noConflict();
    var table = document.getElementById('dlInterior');

    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) 
        {
            var imagePath = $jDecode(row.cells[0]).find('img:first').attr('src');

            if(imagePath == "../icon_active1.gif")
            {
                arrType.push("active");
            }
            else if(imagePath == "../icon_deleted1.gif")
            {
                arrType.push("deleted");
            }
            else
            {
                arrType.push("active");
            }

            var featureValue = $jDecode(row.cells[1]).text();
            arrType.push(featureValue);

            arrType.push("Interior");

            interiorValues.push(arrType);
        }
    }
    alert(interiorValues[5][0]);
}
```

HTML TABLE WHERE DATA IS STORE

```
<TABLE id="dlInteriors" Width="300" Runat="server" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0">
    <TR>
        <TD id="interiortd" vAlign="top" width="350" runat="server"></TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

**Rows are dynamically added on page load.**

Please guide me how I should go ahead on this.

Comment: Show the current code that you are using please. also on PostBack are you checking for If(IsPostBack){} is this code being checked also on a button click..? Look up how to use Session variables as well this is not that difficult.. but without code.. can't lend any advice

Comment: I might be wrong by writing post back..I need this HTml table values while button click event.

Comment: Where is is the Button_Click event..???

Comment: I have a Save button in the same page..which is clicked after data is populated...I need to get the HTML table content somehow when the button click event fires.. there is nothing I can put for button click..`void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant easily get all the values/strings in your HTML page while postback. You could able to get the form fields like input, select, etc in post back using Request.params[""].

But you could **try with hidden variable** (here it is your alternative Viewstate for your HTML table string values)

**When & What you store / how to store /how to access in post back.**

You can try the below steps for above question.

1. Before submit a form, fire a javascript function 'saveTableValues()' 
   which loops your HTML table and creates the object (var) for each row.
2. Prepare a javascript object array (just pushing the item in for each loop)
3. Convert it into **[JSON](http://www.json.org/)** string and assign the whole JSON string 
   into Hidden Field
4. Do post back // just return true in JS
5. In code behind try accessing using Request.Params[""] or 
   normal way like hdnField.Text if it is server side control
6. In Code behing use a **[JavaScript Serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)** 
   or **[JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)** to convert the JSON string into some collection. 
      Recommending JSON.Net here

This may help you.!

**Edit:**

***As your website is running in 1.1 not sure those serializer dll will help you. So you try in XML format instead of JSON. Not sure JSON serializer dll is exist for 1.1 framework***

Comment: Since Javascript Serializing is there after fw 3.5 and not is 1.1...Is there a way I can store this sort of object in  hidden field and get back the values from hidden field..

Comment: You can use JSON.Net library in server side by just adding dll and use http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/ for client side JSON string conversion from your object array.

Comment: I am not sure if that DLL is supported for 1.1 and more over whether I will be allowed to add a new DLL for this purpose..Is this the final way..or any other option is still open..I believe xml serializer is there in 1.1.

Comment: Then simply convert data into XML format string and use in code behind

Comment: Updated the comment in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Create table to run at server like this

`<table id="users" runat="server">`

and you will be able to access it using HtmlTable class,If required create a DataTable dynamically from the table rows and save that in a session. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/li

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery to get the rows values. Then store the data into hiddenfields. This way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function getTableValues() {


         var tds = $('#dlInteriors tr td')

         jQuery.each(tds, function () {
             var url = $(this).children('img:first').attr('src');
             var text = $(this).text();
             if (url)
                 $('#hidValuesStatus').val($('#hidValuesStatus').val() + ',' + url);
             if (text)
                 $('#hidValuesMessages').val($('#hidValuesMessages').val() + ',' + text);
         });

     }

 </script>
```

Call the javascript function on the event "OnClientClick" of your asp:button

```
<TABLE id="dlInteriors" Width="300" Runat="server" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0">
    <TR>
        <TD id="interiortd" vAlign="top" width="350" runat="server"><img src="icon_active1.gif" /></TD>
        <TD id="TD2" vAlign="top" width="350" runat="server">message1</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
         <TD id="TD1" vAlign="top" width="350" runat="server"><img src="icon_deleted1.gif" /></TD>
        <TD id="TD3" vAlign="top" width="350" runat="server">message2</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClientClick="javascript:getTableValues()" Text="SUBMIT" />
<input type="hidden" id="hidValuesMessages" runat="server" />
<input type="hidden" id="hidValuesStatus" runat="server"/>
```

And in the code behind get the data from the hidden fields:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack Then
        If Not IsNothing(Request.Form("hidValuesMessages")) Then

            Dim str As String = Request("hidValuesMessages")

        End If

        If Not IsNothing(Request.Form("hidValuesStatus")) Then

            Dim str2 As String = Request("hidValuesStatus")
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Split the string and get the final values.

Hope this helps!

Regards.